# Is it possible to select multiple conditional counts across three tables in a single SQL query?

Tags: sql

My SQL-fu is too weak for this, and I'm not even sure it's possible in a single SQL call.

Given I have the following tables:

```
PARTNER
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | bloggs |
| 2  | jones  |

PARTNER MANAGER
+----+--------------+------+
| id | partner_id   | name |
+----+--------------+------+
| 1  | 1            | fred |
| 2  | 2            | dave |

COMPANY
+----+--------------------+--------+----------+
| id | partner_manager_id | name   | active   |
+----+--------------------+--------+----------+
| 1  | 1                  | comp1  | true     |
| 2  | 1                  | comp2  | false    |
| 3  | 2                  | comp3  | true     |
| 4  | 2                  | comp4  | true     |
| 5  | 2                  | comp5  | true     |
| 6  | 2                  | comp6  | true     |
```

I'd like to output the following in a single SQL call:

```
+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| partner_name | n_active_companies | n_inactive_companies |
+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| bloggs       | 1                  | 1                    |
| jones        | 4                  | 0                    |
```

I can join the three tables using two `LEFT JOINs` but how I can aggregate the counts (with or without the `WHERE` clause) is eluding me.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, so to speak?

Comment: i prefer to use a SQL view if you want from a single statment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you most of the way there:

```
SELECT
    partner_manager_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN active THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n_active_companies,
    SUM(CASE WHEN active THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS n_inactive_companies
FROM COMPANY
GROUP BY partner_manager_id
```

The rest of your question is basically asking how to join this result to the remaining tables. As you point out, to do this use JOINs.

```
SELECT
    PARTNER.name,
    T1.n_active_companies,
    T1.n_inactive_companies
FROM
PARTNER
LEFT JOIN PARTNER_MANAGER ON partner_id = PARTNER.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        partner_manager_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN active THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS n_active_companies,
        SUM(CASE WHEN active THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS n_inactive_companies
    FROM COMPANY
    GROUP BY partner_manager_id
) T1
ON T1.partner_manager_id = PARTNER_MANAGER.id
```

Comment: That's the core of the answer I was writing... just needs the joins to translate the partner_manager_id to partner.name

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name "Partner Name" 
, c1.cnt "n_active_companies"
, c2.cnt "n_inactive_companies"
from partner p
, (select partner_manager_id id, count(partner_manager_id) cnt from company where active = 'true' group by partner_manager_id) c1
, (select partner_manager_id id, count(partner_manager_id) cnt from company where active = 'false' group by partner_manager_id) c2
where c1.id = p.id
and c2.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name as 'partner_name',
       sum(case when active then 1 else 0) as 'n_active_companies',
       sum(case when active then 0 else 1) as 'n_inactive_companies'
from COMPANY c
   join PARTNER_MANAGER pm on c.partner_manager_id = pm.id
   join PARTNER p on pm.partner_id = p.id
group by p.name
```